# What is the Perl equivalent to pygame?

Tags: perl, pygame

Are there any Perl equivalents for [pygame](http://www.pygame.org/news.html)?

EDIT: I have found SDL and perl-ogre, but I'm looking for something more "high level"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [SDL_Perl](http://arstechnica.com/gaming/news/2006/02/games-perl.ars) can help you.

Comment: While that arstechnica article is nice, it's quite outdated regarding the SDL interface. I believe it still runs as is, but SDL_Perl has been improved a lot lately: http://search.cpan.org/dist/SDL